# Accessing font data on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, truetype, freetype, opentype

I have an OpenGL renderer that uses FreeType to render text.  I would like to be able to use system fonts packaged with Android.  There is a way on iOS to get the ttf font data for system fonts (see accepted answer here: [On iOS, can I access the system-provided font's TTF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692812/on-ios-can-i-access-the-system-provided-fonts-ttf-file)).  Is there something equivalent on Android?  Is there an API for getting the source file for a system font based on the font name, ideally without having to do any guesswork about where certain system files are stored?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10751193/6759241) may help.

Comment: @greeble31 thank you, that's an interesting link.  It looks like what they're doing is rendering the glyphs themselves.  I would prefer to use FreeType for that by handing it the TTF/OTF data though.

Comment: Why guess? All fonts on Android are located in `/system/fonts`, which is not particularly hard to discover with some web searching?

Comment: I did a lot of web searching and saw some comments that not all Android devices store them there, and if that ever changes in the future that method breaks.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: Sure, and then that change will be documented and you can update your application accordingly, but that's hardly something to worry about today.

Comment: I don’t agree and I don’t consider that an acceptable solution.